# Which Definition of 'Increasing' Wins Out W/ Piecewise Defined Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm almost certainly overthinking this, but I ran into some frustration when I tried to solve a problem from a precalculus textbook. The problem asked to state the intervals on which the following function (no function definition provided, only graph) is increasing, decreasing, or constant:

[image]

The ideological problem I'm running into with trying to work this problem is whether to report the interval of decrease as 
$$(-3,0) \cup (2,\infty)$$
or
$$(-3,-2) \cup (-2,0) \cup (2,\infty).$$

This may just be an issue of interpreting the graphic incorrectly, but it seems to me that the function definition changes at $x = -2$, which is what is causing me problems.

On one hand, one definition suggests that a function is decreasing on an open interval $I$ if 
$$ x_1 < x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1) > f(x_2) \qquad \forall x_1,x_2 \in I. $$
From this definition, it is clear that the change in function definition at $x=-2$ would not cause $x=-2$ to be excluded from the interval of decrease.

On the other hand, we also say that a function is decreasing on an interval if the slope of the function is negative on that interval. The way I'm interpreting the graphic, the function changes from a line of slope -1 to a line of slope $-\frac{3}{2}$ at $x = -2$. So, the function would not be differentiable at $x = -2$, thus the slope is undefined so certainly not negative. It seems that the book favors this interpretation, as they adopt the open interval notation for increase/decrease.

Do we just defer to one definition or the other contextually, or is there some unifying idea to settle this?

Comment: It's just logics. If  the function is differentiable, then decrease means negative slope. If it's not differentiable, you cannot use this statement. So, you have to work with the very definition of "decreasing".

Comment: @amsmath That makes sense. If that's the case, how would you reconcile things like corners (x = 2)? We can't include it in the increasing interval or the decreasing interval because we can only talk about increasing and decreasing on open intervals?

Comment: @OGBerglemir: The statement about slope is not a _definition_ of "decreasing". It is just a property that _happens to_ hold if you happen to be restricting yourself to an interval where the derivative exists.

Comment: This page defines "increasing" and "decreasing" with no mention of differentiability https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function

Comment: I see. I was so convinced that the open interval notation was motivated by calculus, rather than just by definition, that I didn't consider this. I appreciate the clarification!

Comment: And note that the function here is *defined* by its graph. You don’t concern yourself with the possible formulas involved, if any.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot say that the function is decreasing on $(-3,0)\cup(2,\infty)$ (compare, e.g., $f(0)$ and $f(2)$)! You can only write that $f$ is decreasing on any of intervals $(-3,0)$ and $(2,\infty)$.

Comment: Completely right, and I missed this myself.